# IntelliJ - previous Tip of the Day

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I read again earlier displayed Tips of the Day?

When I start IntelliJ, if I'm in a hurry I cannot read or note down a useful tip. Such, I would like to read earlier tips. Sorrily, button "Previous Tip" in the tiny window is de-activated. I couldn't find a setting in IJ to activate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the previous tip of the day due to the IDE limitation, please see and follow [IDEA-233662](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233662).